# Display progress bar while loading page in the Wicket framework

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a requirement in the Wicket framework to display a progress bar while loading the page. I've seen lots of examples, but I am unable to figure out any.

I know the timing for page load, so that 20 sec time I want to call the progress bar. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you had a look at this? https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Progressbar

Comment: already look on this..but it requires an additional jar and  i got always progressbar model class not found exception

Comment: Adding wicketstuff-progress dependencies into your pom (or download jar and add to classpath) should resolve ProgressBarModel issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are opening your page by clicking some link/button, one of the options could be as below. The solution has IndicatingAjaxButton with AjaxIndicatorAppender and have new Thread started in the 'onSubmit' method. Before starting new Thread, it has setResponsePage to target page which would take 10 seconds to load.

TestPage with button to open target page TestPage2 which has 10 seconds delay. In your case, it would be 20.

```
   public class TestPage extends WebPage implements IAjaxIndicatorAware {

        AjaxIndicatorAppender indicator;

        public TestPage(final PageParameters parameters) {

            super(parameters);
            setOutputMarkupId(true);
            indicator = new AjaxIndicatorAppender(){
                @Override
                protected CharSequence getIndicatorUrl() {
                    return super.getIndicatorUrl();
                }
            };


            Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form");

            IndicatingAjaxButton button = new IndicatingAjaxButton("submit", form) {
                protected void onSubmit(final AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
                    setResponsePage(new TestPage2(null));
                    new Thread() {
                        public void run() {
                          //Do Nothing
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            };

            button.add(indicator);
            form.add(button);

            add(form);
        }


        @Override
        public String getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId() {
            return indicator.getMarkupId();
        }
    }
```

TestPage.html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>

<style>
    .wicket-ajax-indicator img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    }
</style>

<head>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Wicket Quickstart Archetype Homepage</strong>

<div style="width:50%;">
    <form wicket:id="form">
        <input type="submit" wicket:id="submit" value="Open Test Page 2">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the page with delayed response:

```
public class TestPage2 extends WebPage {

    public TestPage2(PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        add(new Label("delayedLbl", Model.of("Delayed by 10 seconds...")));
    }
}
```

And here is the TestPage2.html:

```
<html xmlns:wicket>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span wicket:id="delayedLbl">Delayed...</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mihir,Thanks for ur solution.But i have already predefined button and this function is work on tht button click,as i understand wicket :id we cant call twice in any method..please give me any solution on this

Comment: In that case, one of the possible solution would be have javascript handle the busy indicator for you. You can look into the link below: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87917

Comment: problem is, you can not combine it with an wizard button